# PHP-array to Java Arraylist using Volley

Tags: java, php, android, database, arraylist

I am trying to convert a PHP-array into a Java ArrayList.

I have this PHP-Code which seems to have no syntax errors:

```
$password = "xxxx";
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "xxxx";
$output = array();

$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (!mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name)) {
    die('Could not select database: ');
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM shopping_items"); //change to         "name"

    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        exit();
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {

    $output[]=$row;
     }

    return $output;
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

It takes one row from the table, so I should get back a PHP-array. 
Now comes the hard part. In Java, I wrote the following code using the Volley library:

```
public void getShopping(String url) {
    //init queue or get from somewhere
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest;
    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,     //URL leads to PHP-File
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    shoppingItems.add(response);    //shopping Items is an ArrayList
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
                    Toast.makeText(ShoppingListActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //got error
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I want to have each item added to `shoppingItems`. But when printing the array out I get an empty string. I think that `StringRequest` is the wrong way to go but I don't know any other way. I read that using `json_encode` is possible but that seems unnecessarily complicated to me. Is there an easier way to do that?

I could not find an answer in previous SO questions. If at all possible, please provide help that involves Volley because it is pretty integrated in my code.

Comment: What is your http header `Content-Type`. Is it `application/json`?

Comment: How do i know? i have the php file located in a PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: If you are the PHP response from your volley, but in your first response there is no http response. So without that response how you will parse the response from Volley?

Your code just return result from the database. But you have show that in browser like `json_encode` or just print in the screen by `print_r` or something. Otherwise you can't have any response from that above PHP code.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but this is for an android mobile application. so i dont want to print it out. (Nothing shown on browser) i just want to store the  values that i get from the php file into the shoppingList.